Trouble Executing Packaged Python Application: Missing File Exception
I'm encountering an issue while trying to execute a package in a Python application (using PyInstaller) that relies on the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file for face recognition.
Despite manually including the file in the bundled package, I'm still receiving a "missing file" exception when running the executable. I have verified the file paths and permissions, but the problem persists.
Could anyone offer insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Has anyone encountered similar challenges when packaging Python applications, and if so, how did you resolve them?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

have you specified the .dat file as an additional 'spec' for PyInstaller to bundle up? see here https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#

I had a similar situation.  I learned that it was related to a temp path being used when my pyinstaller app was executed.  I had to add some code that relied on sys._MEIPASS to fix my issue.
